# Does append create new textView?

Tags: android, textview

***MainActivity.java file***

```
package com.example.sunshineexample_2;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView toyListText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         toyListText = findViewById(R.id.toys_list);

         String[] toyNames = ToyBox.getToyNames();
         for(String Toyname : toyNames){
             toyListText.append(Toyname + "\n");
         }

    }
}
```

In for each loop, the line  `toyListText.append(Toyname + "\n");` , does it create a new textview for every `ToyName`(There are about 30 toys in `String[] toysName`) or just extends the size of existing textview. In xml file I have created a `framelayout` container view and a single `textView`.

***Xml file***

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/toys_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It creates a new String, but not a new TextView.  Nothing but the call to inflate creates a TextView.  However, nothing in your code is updating the textview so you'll never see the changes-  to see the text you'd need to call textView.setText(toyListText) after you're done generating it.

Comment: So it extends the size of existing text view right?

Comment: Append doesn't extend anything-  it returns a string with the two strings combined.  Setting the text of the textView would cause the textView to redraw, and that could cause it to get bigger if your layout width or height is wrap_content.  So yes, in your case it would.